# why the result of string formatter %d is char value on file, scanf("%d",&s_ptr[i])

Tags: c, scanf, structure

```
typedef struct info{            //main record
    int *id;
    unsigned char *name;
}student;

void create(){
    student *s_ptr;
    int num_of_student,i;
    FILE *f_ptr;
    f_ptr = fopen("studentdata.txt","w");

    printf("**How many student to record**\n");
    printf("Enter:");
    scanf("%d",&num_of_student);

    s_ptr = (student*)calloc(num_of_student,sizeof(student));  

    for(i=0;i<num_of_student;i++){
        printf("Enter student id: ");
        scanf("%d",&s_ptr[i]);//while string format is %d it prints char value to the file.  

        fflush(stdin);                                          
        printf("Enter student full name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]",&(s_ptr+i)->name);                          

    fwrite(s_ptr+i,sizeof(struct info),1,f_ptr);
    }


}
```

`scanf("**%d**",&s_ptr[i])` prints its relative character value in file but after changing string format from `%d` to `%s` it prints acutal int value. why?
why the result of string formatter %d is char value on file, scanf("%d",&s_ptr[i]).

Comment: Both of the `scanf` statements in the loop are wrong as well as the `student` struct. Why does your struct contain pointers? Why don't you allocate any memory for those pointers to point to? Why does the first scanf use the address of the struct itself and not a variable in the struct? Get rid of the pointers and fix the first scanf to read into the `id` variable then see what you've got.

Comment: The types in the `scanf` format string don't match the parameters. The `name` should be a `char*` and not `unsigned char*`. It's probably best to start with a simpler program or minimal reproducible example, and extend the code from there.

Comment: I was just getting familiar with pointers so I tried this way but now I knew array will be better for character. Thank for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` has nothing to do with how data is written to a file.

`fwrite` write data to files, and it writes data exactly as it exists in computer memory.

`int` exists as binary representation of the number, the exact value (usually 4 or 8 bytes long).

If you let `fwrite` store those bytes in a file, then look at them as text, you will see some characters, but not the ones representing decimal digits of the number.

This is because your text editor has no way of knowing these bytes belong to C language `int` type and need to be re-interpreted for you to view.

If you want those bytes printed to file in human readable form, use `fprintf` instead.